# Integrating content in Symfony2 into a mapping (GoogleMaps or other) service

Tags: google-maps, symfony, google-maps-api-3

I would like my content (let's say messages) to have a geographical location connected to them - a column storing the geocode or the address in the database - and then use that geocode to display them onto a google map. 
Do I need an abstraction library for that, or could I do it directly with the Google Maps API? 
What would be a best practice in terms of performance and simplicity? (it's already unknown territory for me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start by looking at these libraries and bundles.

https://github.com/willdurand/Geocoder

https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle

You can certainly store/query huge amounts of data in any standard database, but you may want to play with MongoDB for it's geospacial indexes:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/

Comment: Thanks that's an interesting tip for MongoDB as I was wondering what kind of DB I should use in my project.. I wonder if Doctrine plays with MongoDB well

Comment: Actually I want to build an interactive web-app (Ajax based) so maybe I should be looking at javascript/jquery solutions instead of server-side stuff?

Comment: Unfortunately my hosting provider doesn't support MongoDB, he has a strict LAMP setup... Will I have trouble achieving this with MySQL?

Comment: not at all. MongoDB might make certain queries easier out of the box (find all things near this other thing) but MySQL won't be a problem. On a side note, I just noticed this library pop up on github this morning (from the guy that made the IvoryGoogleMapBundle bundle) https://github.com/egeloen/ivory-google-map